# What's a common idiom to say someone is strong?

Tags: idioms, slang, figurative-language

I have no idea how Americans convey the message that someone is physically very strong in informal everyday English. [In my mother language we say someone has a power of a donkey.]

The only equivalents which I found are as below:

> - He is cock strong.
> - He is strong like bull.

I was wondering if you could tell me which one sounds natural in English. If none  makes sense, then could you tell me what a native speaker would say to indicate such a meaning to someone else?

Comment: Diesel (_Dan's brother is diesel since he started lifting weights_), and jacked (_That weightlifter sure is jacked. Too bad he's on steroids_).

Comment: It's "strong as **a** bull". Where did you find "cock strong"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA one of may American friends used it once. He is southern.

Comment: It seems it's written as one word, cockstrong, I wouldn't use it in polite company. You are aware of its secondary and more vulgar  meaning, aren't you? We're not talking about a "rooster" here. This might explain why you received a downvote, to be "cockstrong" is not about physical strength.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I take your word for that. I didn't recognize the secondary meaning. I knew, but I was not sure. However, this is a part of any language. You cannot learn a language omitting some parts. Otherwise, you are selecting it's components. This is a multilateral subject which encompasses various aspects such as street language, colloquialisms, slangs, etc. Especially street language in AmE which can be considered as one of the most open (rude) types of lingual dialects whereas I know seven languages. It makes me think of Russian's street language.

Comment: Don't take my word, check it out! It's true that learning a language encompasses knowing its slang and vulgarities, but I think you should be able to verify yourself the meaning of an expression you hear for the first time, and recall the context in which it was used.

Comment: I can, but it was a part of my question. Supposing that it was somehow rude, could you please clarify whether it was contrary to the forum's rules to cite such a question? I don't think so. If yes, I'm sorry in advance and will not talk about vulgarities from now on. If not, I guess there is no need to such a discussion @Mari-LouA. :)

Comment: Hang on, I didn't DV, I suggested a reason why someone might have done so. I asked you where you heard that expression because I had never heard it myself. I never said that vulgarities, slang etc. should not be studied or learned. But I'm saying had you checked in a dictionary you would have realized that it didn't fit your request. That's all.

Comment: According to todd szabo [*My grandfather use to say it meant a small figured man, but stronger than he looks.*](http://grammarsource.com/2008/03/conflicting-meanings-of-cock-strong/) **and** [*"Cockstrong" meant a guy was a load. And loaded. A pain in the butt to play against. You respected him, in a way — the strength, endurance, earnestness, hustle — ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1AXZsjjRujAC&pg=PA410&dq=cockstrong&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxgrzdm8TRAhVHDMAKHcQ1BPkQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=cockstrong&f=false) So now I'm quite confused :) +1 from me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common English idiom is:

> *He is [strong as an ox](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/strong+as+an+ox)*.

<sub>As a footnote, don't use your first option. Just don't.</sub>

Comment: Just to point out to the OP, this expression is common in British English too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the point is taken. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard [Hercules](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hercules) used as a noun for a man with exceptional strength ( though I'm not a native speaker).

> He is a Hercules.
>    
>   He has the strength of Hercules.

You can also consider the synonyms given in the site.
 Are you specifically looking for idioms related to animals?

Comment: Yes @Nikki. I'm looking for such an idiom and think J.R. has already answered me. However, would be wide open to get other suggestions too.

Comment: Well I also considered 'Hercules' only but the site I nave mentioned writes it as 'a Hercules'. So I don't know. Moreover I'm actually wondering if it can be 'the Hercules' as it is a proper noun. I'm a little confused about it so I just wrote what was in the site. If you can help with some clarification then please do.

Comment: @Jasper Somehow I forgot to mention you :)

Comment: "He is a Hercules" is idiomatic.  It means that he is a (new) Hercules, with the major features of the original Hercules.  You are correct that "the Hercules" would be incorrect in this context, precisely because "Hercules" is a proper noun.  "He has the strength of a Hercules" is grammatically correct, but not idiomatic in American English.  It means that he has the strength of a (new) Hercules.  "He has the strength of Hercules" is correct and idiomatic in American English.  It means that he has the strength of the original Hercules.  In this last context, leaving out the "a" is shorter, …

Comment: … and simpler.  It is simpler because the reader does not need to think of the extra concept of "a (new) Hercules" that is a copy of the original Hercules.  Instead, the reader can just imagine the original Hercules.  "He is Hercules" means either his name is "Hercules", or he is the original Hercules.  Neither of these meanings is quite what you meant.

Comment: @Jasper Thankyou for the clarification. It indeed is much simpler now.

Comment: I think you should have left the first "a" in, but taken the second one out. As @Jasper said, _He is a Hercules_ is idiomatic.